# LINQ compare two lists and remove

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. I want to remove any items from LIST1 that are NOT present in LIST2.

So for example:

```
        var list1 = new List<DownloadTask>();
        list1.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 1, MachineID = 1 });
        list1.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 2, MachineID = 1 });
        list1.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 3, MachineID = 1 });
        list1.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 3, MachineID = 2 });

        var list2 = new List<DownloadTask>();
        list2.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 1, MachineID = 1 });
        list2.Add(new DownloadTask{ OperationID = 3, MachineID = 2 });
```

After run `list1` should contain only items: with combination `operationId = 1`, `machineId = 1` AND `OperationId = 3`, `MachineId =2`.

Comment: In other words, you want to find out the set of common elements in these two lists.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does `DownloadTask` override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly? If so, all you need is:

```
list1 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

That's if you're happy to create a new list, of course. If you really want to remove them from the existing list, it's slightly harder. It would quite possibly be simplest to work out what the result should look like, then clear and re-add:

```
var newList = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
list1.Clear();
list1.AddRange(newList);
```

Of course, all of this *does* require you to implement equality appropriately in `DownloadTask` - but if you haven't done so already, it sounds like it would be a good idea to do so. (Or at least implement `IEqualityComparer<DownloadTask>` somewhere - you can pass a comparer to `Intersect`.)

As a side note, I view "only keep the elements in `list1` which are also in `list2`" (i.e. intersection) as a simpler way of looking at the problem than "remove all elements from `list1` which aren't in `list2`" - the latter is basically a double negative, which is always a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 31):

I think it should be:

```
list1.RemoveAll(x => list2.Exists(y => y.OperationID == x.OperationID && y.MachineID == x.MachineID));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  var lst = (from lst1 in list1 
             where !list2.Any(
                               x => x.OperationID == lst1.OperationID && 
                                    x.MachineID == lst1.MachineID )
             select lst1).ToList();

  list1 = lst.ToList();
```

Please try this it should be worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> equalVal = new List<int>();
equal.AddRange(list1.FindAll(x => list2.Contains(x)));
```

Try this, it will definitely work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).