# Retrieving non-duplicates from 2 Collections using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Background: I have two Collections of different types of objects with different name properties (both strings). Objects in `Collection1` have a field called `Name`, objects in `Collection2` have a field called `Field`.
I needed to compare these 2 properties, and get items from `Collection1` where there is not a match in `Collection2` based on that string property (`Collection1` will always have a greater or equal number of items. All items should have a matching item by Name/Field in `Collection2` when finished).

The question: I've found answers using Lists and they have helped me a little(for what it's worth, I'm using Collections). I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191713/2957232) which appears to be working for me, however I would like to convert what I've done from query syntax (if that's what it's called?) to a LINQ query. See below:

```
//Query for results. This code is what I'm specifically trying to convert.
var result = (from item in Collection1
              where !Collection2.Any(x => x.ColumnName == item.FieldName)
              select item).ToList();  

//** Remove items in result from Collection1**
//...
```

I'm really not at all familiar with either syntax (working on it), but I think I generally understand what this is doing. I'm struggling trying to convert this to LINQ syntax though and I'd like to learn both of these options rather than some sort of nested loop.

End goal after I remove the query results from `Collection1`: `Collection1.Count == Collection2` and the following is true for each item in the collection: `ItemFromCollection1.Name == SomeItemFromCollection2.Field` (if that makes sense...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert this to LINQ methods like this:

```
var result = Collection1.Where(item => !Collection2.Any(x => x.ColumnName == item.FieldName))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. Now I just have to study it compared to the other one...

Answer (score 2):

Your first query is the opposite of what you asked for.  It's finding records that don't have an equivalent.  The following will return all records in Collection1 where there is an equivalent:

```
 var results=Collection1.Where(c1=>!Collection2.Any(c2=>c2.Field==c1.Name));
```

Please note that this isn't the fastest approach, especially if there is a large number of records in collection2.  You can find ways of speeding it up through HashSets or Lookups.

Comment: You're right. I'll try to clean up my post. What I'm doing was finding non-matches, then removing them later at a later time.

Comment: It was a miscommunication on my part. You'll want to change to ...`c1=>!Collection2.Any`... to get the non-dupes. I'm not all that worried about a large amount of records. Should average around 15-ish. Definitely no more than a hundred or so.

Comment: Editted answer to reflect getting non-dups instead of dups.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a list of non duplicate values to be retained then do the following.

```
List<string> listNonDup = new List<String>{"6","1","2","4","6","5","1"};
var singles = listNonDup.GroupBy(n => n)
             .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
             .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

> Yields: 2, 4, 5

if you want a list of all the duplicate values then you can do the opposite

```
var duplicatesxx = listNonDup.GroupBy(s => s)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).ToList();
```